# How can I perform (min,max) over multiple columns in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    preds        geoLong      geoLat
8      11     -78.949609   39.154228
9      11    -128.489609   38.154228
10     11      -48.48969   37.154228
```

I am grouping on a column (`preds`)

```
gbr = df.groupby(['preds'])
```

When I perform the following I get the incorrect results from that column:

```
gbr.agg({'geoLong': 'max'})
```

Comment: The (min,max) aggregations appear to work with positive data but inverts the result with negative data.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need:

```
gbr.agg({'geoLong': 'max', 'geoLat':'min'})
```

But first check `dtypes` to see if columns `geoLong` and `geoLat` are numeric:

```
print (df.dtypes)
preds      object
geoLong    object
geoLat     object
dtype: object
```

If there are `object`s (obviously `string`s) you'll need to parse it:

```
cols = ['geoLong','geoLat']
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
```

If it returns an error because of bad data, use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) which replaces all bad data with `NaN`s:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'l'

```
cols = ['geoLong','geoLat']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Jezrael,  Yes, you caught my error.  It was a string and the min/max was being done on a string. Thanks, Marc

Comment: Some problem? Can you explain? I believe som solution can be found. Thanks.